# what happens if browser is refreshed before ajax callback returns

Tags: browser, callback, refresh

I have an ajax call which takes long time to return. If the user clicks the browser refresh before the callback is called, I don't see the callback getting executed at all. Is this the expected behavior.

thanks
P

Comment: The browser refresh is going to completely reset the environment that the Javascript making the Ajax call is working in.  What environment would the callback execute in, the new refreshed page?  To execute the callback in this circumstance would have unexpected consequences, indeed since its quite similar to what would happen if they navigated to another page, to execute the callback would even be classed as a security concern.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it make sense why it does not return to callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes because the browser its not wating any more for the callback. you cant prenvent using a modal windows or with onbeforeunload event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "please do no refresh the page";
    }
</script>
```